# How to prevent @SpringBootTest from discovering OAuth2 configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have an unintuitive security model for my application:

- Mobile client calls `/api/sso/login` with a JWT token issued from a separate authorization server.
- The JWT is validated with the authorization server
- This same `/api/sso/login` endpoint, for reasons that are out of my control, must exchange this access token from the authorization server for a JWT issued by my service that embeds additional tokens required to interact with downstream services.
- Each subsequent request to my service for data must contain a JWT issued by my service, with the embedded tokens, in order to aggregate data from a downstream service. It is not enough to use the access token issued from the authorization server (thereby making my server a resource server) because my server is essentially a proxy for another service that requires a JSESSIONID cookie to be set on each request in order to get data.
- The `JwtTokenUtil` bean referenced below has the job of constructing these custom JWT tokens, and later validating them when they come in on a request. This validation is done in a `JwtTokenAuthenticationProvider` which is registered with the `AuthenticationManager`.

I'm using this library: https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot to manage discovery of `.well-known/openid-configuration`, and validating JWT tokens before they are injected into my controller in a Spring Boot application. In my integration tests annotated with @SpringBootTest or @RestClientTest, it appears the framework attempts to discover this endpoint on the internet and I can't find any docs on how to mock that out or ignore it. It ends up either making a dependency of our integration tests that we can actually reach out to our Auth0 tenant on the public internet, or if we use fake issuer/audience URLs each test takes 45 seconds before timing out and moving on. The error I'm seeing is:

> Failed to process '.well-known/openid-configuration' metadata. Using defaults for Okta.

I can get around this by using URLs that will return this metadata, but that means that my integration tests which can run without connecting to external services now have a dependency on being able to reach these live services. I believe the right thing to do is to mock out this interaction, but I don't see how that's possible with this library.

Here is what the tests initially looked like:

```java
package com.mobileapi.event_log;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.mobileapi.config.JwtTokenUtil;
import com.mobileapi.results_services.analytics_log_event.dto.AnalyticsLogEventDTO;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import static com.mobileapi.filter.CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter.JWT_TOKEN_PREFIX;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
class EventLogControllerIntegrationTests {
    private static final String EVENT_LOG_REQUEST_PATH = "/api/v1/event-log";
    private static final String DEVICE_ID = "abc";
    @MockBean
    JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    @MockBean
    EventLogService eventLogService;
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("succeeds with a valid bearer token")
    void succeedsWithValidBearerToken() throws Exception {
        final String token = "abc123";
        when(jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(token)).thenReturn(true);

        mockMvc.perform(
                        post(EVENT_LOG_REQUEST_PATH)
                                .queryParam("deviceId", DEVICE_ID)
                                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mock(AnalyticsLogEventDTO.class)))
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, JWT_TOKEN_PREFIX + token)
                )
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isAccepted());
    }

    @Nested
    @DisplayName("returns unauthorized")
    class ReturnsUnauthorized {
        @Test
        @DisplayName("when there is no bearer token")
        void withoutBearerToken() throws Exception {
            mockMvc.perform(post(EVENT_LOG_REQUEST_PATH)
                            .queryParam("deviceId", DEVICE_ID)
                            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mock(AnalyticsLogEventDTO.class)))
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
        }

        @Test
        @DisplayName("when the bearer token is invalid")
        void whenTokenIsInvalid() throws Exception {
            final String token = "abc123";
            when(jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(token)).thenReturn(false);
            mockMvc.perform(
                            post(EVENT_LOG_REQUEST_PATH)
                                    .queryParam("deviceId", DEVICE_ID)
                                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mock(AnalyticsLogEventDTO.class)))
                                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                    .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, JWT_TOKEN_PREFIX + token)
                    )
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
        }
    }
}
```

and here are the contents of `application-test.properties`:

```
okta.oauth2.audience=https://test.com
okta.oauth2.issuer=https://test.com/
```

Here is an example of what the test looked like after following [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-oauth-testing-access-control). Please note that injecting a JWT into MockMvc here isn't desired, because for these endpoints my service would never accept the JWT from the authorization server. Instead it must receive a `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken` which was validated in the Spring Security filter chain dedicated to these endpoints by the `JwtTokenUtil`.

```java
package com.mobileapi.event_log;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.mobileapi.config.JwtTokenUtil;
import com.mobileapi.results_services.analytics_log_event.dto.AnalyticsLogEventDTO;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static com.mobileapi.filter.CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter.JWT_TOKEN_PREFIX;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.anonymous;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
class EventLogControllerIntegrationTests {
    private static final String EVENT_LOG_REQUEST_PATH = "/api/v1/event-log";
    private static final String DEVICE_ID = "abc";
    @MockBean
    JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    @MockBean
    EventLogService eventLogService;
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("succeeds with a valid bearer token")
    void succeedsWithValidBearerToken() throws Exception {
        final String token = "abc123";
        when(jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(token)).thenReturn(true);

        mockMvc.perform(
                        post(EVENT_LOG_REQUEST_PATH)
                                .queryParam("deviceId", DEVICE_ID)
                                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mock(AnalyticsLogEventDTO.class)))
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, JWT_TOKEN_PREFIX + token)
                                .with(anonymous())
                )
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isAccepted());
    }

    @Nested
    @DisplayName("returns unauthorized")
    class ReturnsUnauthorized {
        @Test
        @DisplayName("when there is no bearer token")
        void withoutBearerToken() throws Exception {
            mockMvc.perform(post(EVENT_LOG_REQUEST_PATH)
                            .queryParam("deviceId", DEVICE_ID)
                            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mock(AnalyticsLogEventDTO.class)))
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .with(anonymous()))
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
        }

        @Test
        @DisplayName("when the bearer token is invalid")
        void whenTokenIsInvalid() throws Exception {
            final String token = "abc123";
            when(jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(token)).thenReturn(false);
            mockMvc.perform(
                            post(EVENT_LOG_REQUEST_PATH)
                                    .queryParam("deviceId", DEVICE_ID)
                                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mock(AnalyticsLogEventDTO.class)))
                                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                    .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, JWT_TOKEN_PREFIX + token)
                                    .with(anonymous())
                    )
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
        }
    }
}
```

What complicates these tests are that there are multiple Spring Security filter chains that run. One looks specifically at a single SSO login endpoint and treats our server as a resource server, which necessitates the use of okta-spring-boot in order to discover the Auth0 issuer. All other endpoints, such as the one under test, are secured with a JWT token that is issued by the same server that hosts this endpoint, and is parsed/validated by the `JwtTokenUtil` bean. Understanding that this completely re-invents the wheel for using OAuth2 to begin with, this is an unfortunate temporary technical limitation that we must accommodate because of the software we are integrating with and it cannot change.

Here is the Spring security config:

```java
package com.mobileapi.config;

import com.mobileapi.filter.CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import jakarta.servlet.Filter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    private static final String MOBILE_BACKEND_BASE_PATH_MATCHER = "/api/**";
    /**
     * The path of the login endpoint that a mobile client can use to authenticate the user with JWT authentication.
     */
    private static final String JWT_V1_AUTHENTICATION_LOGIN_PATH = "/api/v1/authenticate";
    /**
     * The path of the login endpoint that a mobile client can use to exchange an OAuth2 access token for a JWT issued
     * by this service.
     */
    private static final String SSO_V1_AUTHENTICATION_LOGIN_PATH = "/api/v1/sso/authenticate";

    @Autowired
    private CustomTokenAuthenticationProvider customTokenAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenAuthenticationProvider jwtTokenAuthenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(customTokenAuthenticationProvider);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(jwtTokenAuthenticationProvider);

        // Required to set this to null, otherwise requests that cannot be authenticated by the providers will delegate
        // back to the providers as their own parents and infinitely recurse.
        authenticationManagerBuilder.parentAuthenticationManager(null);
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain oauth2FilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .logout(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement((sessionManagement) -> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .securityMatcher(SSO_V1_AUTHENTICATION_LOGIN_PATH)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(withDefaults()))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain customAuthFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authManager) throws Exception {
        return http
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .logout(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement((sessionManagement) -> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .securityMatcher(MOBILE_BACKEND_BASE_PATH_MATCHER)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.requestMatchers(JWT_V1_AUTHENTICATION_LOGIN_PATH).permitAll())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.requestMatchers(getRequestMatchers()).authenticated())
                .addFilterBefore(getCustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter(authManager), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    private RequestMatcher getRequestMatchers() {
        return new AndRequestMatcher(
                new AntPathRequestMatcher(MOBILE_BACKEND_BASE_PATH_MATCHER),
                new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(JWT_V1_AUTHENTICATION_LOGIN_PATH))
        );
    }

    private Filter getCustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        return new CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter(getRequestMatchers(), authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

Comment: ***treats our server as a resource server, which necessitates the use of okta-spring-boot in order to discover the Auth0 issuer*** this is wrong: you don't need Okta starter (`spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` does it pretty well, with or without `spring-addons-starter-oidc`, as proved in the many [samples](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples) and [tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#securing-spring-applications-with-oauth2) in my repo

Comment: ***what the test looked like after following [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-oauth-testing-access-control)***. I doubt you followed all it contains: you are using only `.with(anonymous())` which explicitly populates all your test cases security context with an `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` => you never simulate an authorized request.

Comment: As a side note, implementing your own JWT issuance mechanism on a resource server is generally considered a worst practice (like you seem doing in this `JwtTokenUtil`, but as we don't have the source, we can hardly tell). You have an authorization server, use it to issue all access tokens (only follow OAuth2 best practices, do not try to invent something new).

Comment: I agree what we have is not ideal and is not the way it should be done. If I had the ability to make it the way it should be, yes I would ensure that all resources in this service would be secured with the token issued by the authorization server. We have to support this bad integration as a temporary measure because of the reality of software. It would be helpful if we could accept that limitation as an assumption of this implementation and move forward with that reality in mind.

Comment: **I doubt you followed all it contains: you are using only .with(anonymous()) which explicitly populates all your test cases security context with an AnonymousAuthenticationToken => you never simulate an authorized request.**
This is not true; the `JwtTokenUtil` is there because that endpoint has to be secured using a custom token issued by this service, not the authorization server. In this integration test, I don't need to interact with the authorization server because a token from the authorization server cannot be used to access this endpoint.

Comment: You have obviously not understood how the security context is populated in a test with `MockMvc`. It would be helpful if you could accept how it works and try to use the `JwtRequestPostProcessor` returned by `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt()` (instead of the `anonymous` one, as instructed in the article). If your `CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter` builds something else than a `JwtAuthenticationToken`, then you'll have to write your own `RequestPostProcessor` (maybe taking inspiration from `JwtRequestPostProcessor`)

Comment: I don't think I did a good job describing the security model so I will update my question with the relevant details; the application has to support either a PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken (for all endpoints except the SSO login endpoint), and a JWT for only the single SSO login endpoint. But the classes under test are not being tested with assuming they get the JWT that was validated by the authorization server; instead they are secured by a custom token that our server issues. That's why I don't think configuring my test to inject a JWT is the right answer for this use case.

Comment: The `JwtRequestPostProcessor` does not inject a `JWT` in test request `Authorization` header. It populates the test security context with a `JwtAuthenticationToken` (with `MockMvc`, request authorization mechanism is skipped, we just build the resulting `Authentication` instance with a request post-processor and inject it in the security context)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255938/discussion-between-daniel-allen-and-ch4mp).

Answer (score 0):

Mock the `JwtDecoder` (or the authentication manager if you customized it) and use `MockMvc` with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` (or `WebTestClient` with `AutoConfigureWebTestClient` in a reactive app). This will:

- remove the need for the authorization server to reachable
- enable you to mock authentication and enable to test access control rules

Mire details in [this article I wrote for Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-oauth-testing-access-control) or on [my github repo.](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had tried this approach after reading your article but it was not working for me. I will update my original post with additional details on what a test looks like.

Comment: Added additional context to my original post, hoping this helps clarify what may not be working here. Thank you for your help.